# applet java aplicação

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.List;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class MemoryGame2 extends java.applet.Applet implements ActionListener
{
    private JCheckBox check1,check2,check3;
    Font f; 
    TextField msg1, msg2, password,t;
    CheckboxGroup cbg;
    Checkbox courier, timesRoman, helvetica;
    String s;
    Label mostra;           
    public int delay = 1000; //1000 milliseconds

    public void Contador()
    {
        ActionListener counter = new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                tempo++;
                TempoScore.setText("Tempo: " + tempo);
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, counter).start();
    }

    public void updateHitMiss() 
    {
        HitScore.setText("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore.setText("Falhou: " + Miss);
        PontosScore.setText("Pontos: " + Pontos);
    }

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Jogo da Memoria");
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500; // pixels
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500; // pixels
    private JButton exitBtn, baralharBtn, solveBtn, restartBtn, maximoBtn, definicoesBtn;
    ImageIcon ButtonIcon = createImageIcon("card1.png");
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    private int Hit, Miss, Pontos, Maximo;
    public int tempo = 0;   
    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] btnID = new int[2];
    private int[] btnValue = new int[2];
    private JLabel HitScore, MissScore, TempoScore, PontosScore, MaximoScore;
    private JPanel gamePnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel scorePnl = new JPanel();

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) 
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = MemoryGame.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) 
        {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } 
        else  return null;
    }

    public MemoryGame2()
    {
        createGUI();
        createJPanels();
        setArrayListText();
        window.setTitle("Jogo da Memoria");
        //window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);
        Contador();
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        HitScore = new JLabel("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore = new JLabel("Falhou: " + Miss);
        TempoScore = new JLabel("Tempo: " + tempo);
        PontosScore = new JLabel("Pontos: " + Pontos);  
        exitBtn = new JButton("Sair");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        baralharBtn = new JButton("Baralhar");
        baralharBtn.addActionListener(this);
        solveBtn = new JButton("Resolver");
        solveBtn.addActionListener(this);
        restartBtn = new JButton("Recomecar");
        restartBtn.addActionListener(this);
        maximoBtn = new JButton("Pontuacoes");
        maximoBtn.addActionListener(this);
        definicoesBtn = new JButton("Definicoes");
        definicoesBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void createJPanels()
    {
        gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
        }
        buttonPnl.add(baralharBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(exitBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(solveBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(restartBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(maximoBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(definicoesBtn);
        buttonPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        scorePnl.add(HitScore);
        scorePnl.add(MissScore);
        scorePnl.add(TempoScore);
        scorePnl.add(PontosScore);
        scorePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        window.add(scorePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(gamePnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void setArrayListText()
    { 
        List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        Collections.shuffle(lista);
        gameList.addAll(lista);
    }

    public boolean sameValues()
    {
        if (btnValue[0] == btnValue[1])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void pass() 
    {
        s = "123";
        msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); msg1.setEditable(false);
        password = new TextField(12); password.setEchoCharacter('*');
        msg2 = new TextField(30); msg2.setEditable(false);
        add(msg1); add(password); add(msg2);
    }
    /*
    public boolean action(Event e, Object o) 
    {
        if (e.target instanceof TextField)
        if (e.target ==password)
        if (e.arg.equals(s)) msg2.setText("Acesso permitido");
        else msg2.setText("Password invalida.");
        return true;
    } */
    /*
    class EscutaJanela extends WindowAdapter
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            if (exitBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (baralharBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
                Collections.shuffle(lista);
                gameList.addAll(lista);
            }

            if (solveBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);                  
                    gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);
                    gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));       
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {           
                if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource())
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
                    counter++;

                    if(Hit==7)
                    {
                        if (counter == 2)
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(false);
                            Hit = Hit +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                        }                   
                    }

                    if(Hit==8)
                    {  
                        int PontuacaoMax=0;
                        PontuacaoMax=Pontos;
                        window = new JFrame(" FIM DO JOGO ");           
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n PARABENS FINALIZOU O JOGO ! TOTAL DE PONTOS: "+PontuacaoMax);    
                        int[] anArray;
                        int w=0;
                        anArray = new int[20];
                        anArray[w] = PontuacaoMax;
                        System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                        w++;
                        window.add("Center", label3);               
                        window.show();                      
                        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("fogo.jpg");                  
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
                        window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        window.pack();  
                        window.setVisible(true); 
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);

                        //AudioClip audio = Applet.newAudioClip(cl.getResource("bottle-open.wav"));
                        //audio.play();                 
                    }

                    if (counter == 3)
                    {               
                        if (sameValues())
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                            Hit = Hit +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setText("");
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setText("");
                            Miss = Miss +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos - 5;                       
                        }
                        counter = 1; 
                    }
                    /*if (Pontos <= 0)
                    {
                        Pontos=0;
                    } */
                    if (counter == 1) // se carregar 1º botão
                    {
                        btnID[0] = i;
                        btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
                    }
                    if (counter == 2) // se carregar 2º botão
                    {
                        btnID[1] = i;
                        btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (restartBtn == e.getSource()) // apaga a grelha
            { 
                Hit=0;
                Miss=0;
                tempo=-1;
                Pontos=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setText("");
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(true);
                    gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);    
                }
            }  

            if (maximoBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
            {
                window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Melhores Pontuacoes:"); 
                int Max=0,PontuacaoMax=0;           

                //private static int maxValue(char[] chars) 
                //{
                    //int  = chars[0]; 
                    /*
                    int[] anArray;
                    anArray = new int[20];
                    for (int w = 0; w < anArray.length; w++) 
                    {
                        if (anArray[w]>= Max) 
                        {
                            Max = anArray[w];
                            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+Max);
                            window.add("Center", label2);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                    JLabel label5 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao: " +PontuacaoMax );
                    window.add("Center", label5); */
                    //return Pontos;
                //}
                /*
                anArray[w]=0;
                int w;
                for(w=0;w<20;w++)
                {
                    if (anArray[w]>=PontuacaoMax)
                    {
                        PontuacaoMax=anArray[w];
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax);
                        window.add("Center", label2);
                    }
                } 
                */ 
                if (Pontos >= PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax); 
                    //Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
                    //v.add(PontuacaoMax);System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }
                if (Pontos < PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: 0");         
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }    

                window.show();                      
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("trofeu.jpg");           
                JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                window.pack();  
                window.setVisible(true); 
            }

            if (definicoesBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
            { /*
                window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Password:");
                window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
                // pass(); 
                s = "123";
                msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); 
                msg1.setEditable(false);
                password = new TextField(12); 
                password.setEchoCharacter('*');
                msg2 = new TextField(30); 
                msg2.setEditable(false);
                add(msg1); 
                add(password); 
                add(msg2); 

                window.resize(300,300);
                window.show();                      
                window.pack();  
                window.setVisible(true);    
                //action(e,o);  */      

                definicoesBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {    
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
                    {    
                        window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Definicoes:");              
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Escolha Nivel Dificuldade:");           
                        window.add("West", label3);                                     
                        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("definicoes.jpg");
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                        window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                        JRadioButton aRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Facil ");
                        JRadioButton bRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Medio ");
                        JRadioButton cRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Dificil ");

                        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() 
                        {
                              public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changEvent) 
                              {
                                    AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton)changEvent.getSource();
                                    ButtonModel aModel = aButton.getModel();
                                    boolean armed = aModel.isArmed();
                                    boolean pressed = aModel.isPressed();
                                    boolean selected = aModel.isSelected();

                                    aRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                           
                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
                                            //System.out.println("4x4");
                                        }
                                    });
                                    bRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                                       
                                            JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[18];

                                             for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                            {
                                                gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
                                                gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
                                            } 

                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6)); /*
                                            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                            {
                                                gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
                                            }           */                                                  
                                        }
                                    });
                                    cRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                                                                                   
                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));                                                
                                        }
                                    });
                               }
                        };
                        panel.add(aRadioButton);
                        group.add(aRadioButton);
                        panel.add(bRadioButton);
                        group.add(bRadioButton);
                        panel.add(cRadioButton);
                        group.add(cRadioButton);
                        aRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        bRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        cRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        window.add(panel);                      
                        window.pack();  
                        window.setVisible(true); 
                    }    
                });             
            }
        updateHitMiss();
    }    
    //new MemoryGame();
}
```

Este codigo em Notepad++, só funciona a compilar como aplicação, mas quero agora a funcionar tal e qual como *applet*, meu código HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title> Applet </title>
  </head>
  <body>
     Applet Jogo da Memória:
     <br>
     <applet code="MemoryGame2.class"  width="600"  height="50">
     </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Resultado abre a janela, a dizer *applet started* mas a janela está totalmente em branco, tambem abre ao mesmo tempo a minha aplicação (codigo acima).